# Not able to generate a Let's Encrypt Certificat

Tags: nginx, ssl, laravel-forge, laravel-octane

I am using Laravel Forge to manage my servers and websites. So generating SSL certificates via Let's Encrypt is also done vie Forge. Somehow one of my domains throws me an error (see attached).

This domain is running on a server which holds several other domains. The nginx configuration is exactly the same.

The application is a Laravel app running on Laravel Octane.

Error:

> 2022-06-13 10:41:26 URL:https://forge-certificates.laravel.com/le/1441847/1663342/ecdsa?
> env=production [4653] -> "letsencrypt_script1655109686" [1] Cloning
> into 'letsencrypt1655109686'... Note: switching to
> '91cccc0c234e4decf0a19595fa19a6f306788032'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
> experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
> you make in this state without impacting any branches by switching
> back to a branch.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
> may do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
>
> git switch -c
>
> Or undo this operation with:
>
> git switch -
>
> Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to
> false
>
> HEAD is now at 91cccc0 ensure newline before new section in
> openssl.cnf ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid) (result:
> ["type"]  "http-01" ["status"]    "invalid"
> ["error","type"]  "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection"
> ["error","detail"]    "111.222.333.444: Fetching
> http://my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw:
> Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)"
> ["error","status"]    400
> ["error"] {"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection","detail":"111.222.333.444:
> Fetching
> http://my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw:
> Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)","status":400}
> ["url"]   "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/119151352296/awZDUg"
> ["token"] "_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw"
> ["validationRecord",0,"url"]  "http://www.my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw"
> ["validationRecord",0,"hostname"] "www.my-domain.de"
> ["validationRecord",0,"port"] "80"
> ["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved",0]  "111.222.333.444"
> ["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved",1]  "2a01:4f8:141:333::84"
> ["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved"]    ["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"]
> ["validationRecord",0,"addressUsed"]  "2a01:4f8:141:333::84"
> ["validationRecord",0]    {"url":"http://www.my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw","hostname":"www.my-domain.de","port":"80","addressesResolved":["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"],"addressUsed":"2a01:4f8:141:333::84"} ["validationRecord",1,"url"] "http://www.my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw"
> ["validationRecord",1,"hostname"] "www.my-domain.de"
> ["validationRecord",1,"port"] "80"
> ["validationRecord",1,"addressesResolved",0]  "111.222.333.444"
> ["validationRecord",1,"addressesResolved",1]  "2a01:4f8:141:333::84"
> ["validationRecord",1,"addressesResolved"]    ["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"]
> ["validationRecord",1,"addressUsed"]  "111.222.333.444"
> ["validationRecord",1]    {"url":"http://www.my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw","hostname":"www.my-domain.de","port":"80","addressesResolved":["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"],"addressUsed":"111.222.333.444"}
> ["validationRecord",2,"url"]  "http://my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw"
> ["validationRecord",2,"hostname"] "my-domain.de"
> ["validationRecord",2,"port"] "80"
> ["validationRecord",2,"addressesResolved",0]  "111.222.333.444"
> ["validationRecord",2,"addressesResolved",1]  "2a01:4f8:141:333::84"
> ["validationRecord",2,"addressesResolved"]    ["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"]
> ["validationRecord",2,"addressUsed"]  "2a01:4f8:141:333::84"
> ["validationRecord",2]    {"url":"http://my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw","hostname":"my-domain.de","port":"80","addressesResolved":["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"],"addressUsed":"2a01:4f8:141:333::84"} ["validationRecord"] [{"url":"http://www.my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw","hostname":"www.my-domain.de","port":"80","addressesResolved":["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"],"addressUsed":"2a01:4f8:141:333::84"},{"url":"http://www.my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw","hostname":"www.my-domain.de","port":"80","addressesResolved":["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"],"addressUsed":"111.222.333.444"},{"url":"http://my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw","hostname":"my-domain.de","port":"80","addressesResolved":["111.222.333.444","2a01:4f8:141:333::84"],"addressUsed":"2a01:4f8:141:333::84"}] ["validated"] "2022-06-13T08:41:47Z")

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as it stands because not related to programming, and you do obfuscates badly (also why not obfuscating IPv6 too? kind of pointless to obfuscate IPv4 so badly, because `111.222.333.444` is NOT an IPv4 address). Also you have the answer in the log (not trimmed!) you publish: "Fetching http://my-domain.de/.well-known/acme-challenge/_bL98lTvqMOeJG-NCeLzl2Z3VWUm7EJBa1i6IEBDuLw: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)" ["error","status"] 400 ["error"] " So you have to fix this connectivity issue, no one here can help on that, and it is unrelated to code.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek of course the ip is masked so my real ip is not visible. Calling the URL provided by the log works fine for post and get requests. There is no timeout issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. Laravel Forge does not support IPv6 out of the box. So you either have to configure Forge to use IPv6 as well or remove all AAAA records pointing to the server managed by Laravel Forge.

Comment: Thank you so much, this just fixed my issue and saved me from tearing my hair out!